# Gaps in geom_line output of ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, data-visualization

I am plotting a set of data using geom_line in ggplot but there are gaps in portions of the curve. When I plot the data in Excel these gaps do not appear. I thought that maybe I had duplicate x-values in my data but I do not. Any suggestions? All I am doing is taking my larger data frame and selecting for one condition.

```
data %>%
  filter(condition == c("one")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(time,value)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = "red") , size = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,150),
      breaks = seq(0,150, by = 20),
      expand = c(0,0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0,10),
      breaks = seq(0, 10, by = 1),
      expand = c(0,0))
```

[Data plot with vertical gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJZR2.png)

Comment: What do your y values range from? This kind of has the feel of missing segments when points go outside of your y axis limits or something.  Try adding a reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so folks can take a closer look! :)

Comment: In `geom_line` remove `aes(color = "red")` and use just `color = "red"`, with no `aes()`.